# How to be notified when there is mention and DM in twitter

Tags: php, twitter, notifications

I'm wondering how Boxcar works, anybody knows? I know how to do the push notification from server to iPhone, but I have no clue of how to create the server to get the @reply and dm from twitter in real time. Any suggestion on what I should look into to create the server? Should I use Twitter's streaming API or User Streams API?

Any sample code, in PHP preferably, will be great :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way to get mentions and DMs in realtime for more then a single user is the [Site Stream API](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/site_streams). You can use the [Phirehose library](http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/) with the OAuth/userstream patch to connect. Unfortunately Site Streams is currently in closed beta and you may not be able to get access for a little while.

Otherwise you pretty much have to poll the REST API frequently to simulate realtime.